# WPF - Binding is working one time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following begginer project, and have a wierd effect. I want the button to add one element to the ComboBox every time it is clicked.

What happens is that when I start the app, click `n` times on the button and then open the ComboBox, it shows me `n` items as expected. But no matter how often I click the button atfer that, there will be no new items in the ComboBox.

**MainWindow.xaml**:

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_binding_combobox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_binding_combobox"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Add item to combobox" Click="Button_Click" />
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ComboBoxItems}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs** (code-behind):

```
namespace WPF_binding_combobox {
    using System.Windows;

    public partial class MainWindow : Window {

        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new La();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            La l = this.DataContext as La;
            l.AddItem();
        }

    }
}
```

**La.cs**

```
namespace WPF_binding_combobox {
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;

    class La : INotifyPropertyChanged {
        private int counter;
        private IList<string> cbItems;

        public IList<string> ComboBoxItems {
            get {
                return this.cbItems;
            }
            set {
                this.cbItems = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("ComboBoxItems");
            }
        }


        public La() {
            this.cbItems = new List<string>();
            this.counter = 0;
        }

        public void AddItem() {
            var temp = this.ComboBoxItems;
            temp.Add("abc" + (++this.counter));
            this.ComboBoxItems = temp;
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried the debugger, and it shows me that there are items added to the backing field and the RaisePropertyChanged is called. For some reason, the UI does not show me any thing that changes after the first click.

I have tried setting `Mode=OneWay` or `Mode=TowWay`, there was no change.

Why is the ComboBox not getting updated after I open it for the first time?

Comment: Use ObservableCollection !

Answer (score 3):

You are using `IList` which has no way of informing View that items has been added or removed after initial binding (like you said).

You should use `ObservableCollection`. As the name suggests, it works on observer pattern where your View will be observer.

```
public ObservableCollection<string> ComboBoxItems
{
    get
    {
        return cbItems;
    }
}
```

and in `AddItem` you only need to to this

```
 public void AddItem()
 {
    ComboBoxItems.Add("abc" + (++this.counter));
 }
```

---

**Off Topic:**

If you want to use MVVM pattern, don't write any code in Code-behind. Use Delegate Commands to bind to buttons. (Google will help).

Even assigning DataContext can be removed to XAML like this

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <myassembly:LA />
</Window.DataContext>
```

Till then, have a local variable in View which would save you casting hackles everytime.

```
private La _dataContext;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _dataContext = new La();
    this.DataContext = _dataContext
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    _dataContext.AddItem();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether you are using an `ObservableCollection<T>` or an `IList<T>` doesn't really matter if you *reset* the source collection property each time you want to update the `ComboBox`.

You should either use a single instance of an `ObservableCollection` that you add all items to or set your source property to a *new* `IList<string>`.

If you modify your `AddItem()` method slightly it works as expected:

```
public void AddItem()
{
    var temp = new List<string>(this.ComboBoxItems);
    temp.Add("abc" + (++this.counter));
    this.ComboBoxItems = temp;
}
```

Comment: You ans is nice and surely will work. but it seems OP is a learner. Instead of correcting his problem, we should guide him to correct approach of MVVM.

Comment: Maybe you should read my answer again. "Whether you are using an ObservableCollection<T> or an IList<T> doesn't really matter if you reset the source collection property each time you want to update the ComboBox". And there is nothing that says that it is *Always" better not to reset a collection property.